# Android sendTextMessage not working for second account even if SEND_SMS permission is granted

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager

I am trying to write a Sms app.

When I use

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, body, null, null);
```

to send sms, the app works fine on the main account, but it always fail to send sms when I switch to the second account.

I already give the second account permission to send sms in Settings, and also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

in Manifest.xml
Also, since the target sdk version is 23, I also request permission during the run time. However, it is still not working after all permissions are granted. T_T

It will not crash, it just does nothing. Therefore, I think it is an issue related to permission, I just don't know where the problem is.

Anyone one help?

**UPDATE:**

```
public void sendSMS(Context context, String phoneNumber, String messageBody)
{
    Intent sentIntent = new Intent("SENT");
    sentIntent.putExtra("phone_number", phoneNumber);
    sentIntent.putExtra("message_body", messageBody);

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);

    /**Catch the sms send fail to check wether cause by permission deny**/
    try{
        Log.d("Debug phoneNumber", phoneNumber );
        Log.d("Debug messageBody", messageBody);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageBody, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The two `Log.d()` methods can work, but `smsManager.sendTextMessage()` does nothing if switch to the secondary account.

Comment: Post the part of your code which is not woring\

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I have updated the question with the code. Thx